# Create ranking from 0 to 10

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using Microsoft Excel for Mac 2017.
I have some tables with the frequency of certain animals, and others with the frequency of certain plants. In order to compare them, I wanted to create a ranking that goes from 0 to 10 in every table, so to integrate them efficiently later in a new table.

I am new to Excel, but I tried to create a ranking of the first table and:
(1) the repeat formula function does not work (dragging the bottom right corner does not work, even if I am locking the cell with $) 
(2) It obviously creates rankings with numbers as high as 28 - which I don't want as the lists have different lengths. 
I want every rank to be from 0 to 10, so to show later the most common plants and animals.
A possible solution would be to create different intervals categories from 0 to 10 in every table, but I need a function that would find me the appropriate interval according to the minimum and maximum value.
E.g. if in a table 1 I have these frequencies (even if with actually many more plants):
Rye: 13%
Lentil 2,60%
Apple 0,1%
Grape 29%
Bread wheat 17%

and in table 2 I might have a percentage up to 70%, I can't use the same categories, so I have to create appropriate intervals for each table.

How can I do it? I hope this question has not been posted already, I tried looking around!

Thank you in advance

EDIT: Added images as suggested
Examples of my tables that I have to integrate using rankings (or what you suggest)

[Animals]

[image]

[Plants]

[image]

Comment: Please share some sample data with us,, help to fix the issue !!

Comment: @RajeshS you are right. Just added some images.

Comment: Build pivot (on another worksheet for example) using Name and Percent columns for each table. Sort by Percent. Add ranking column (if current percent = previos percent then previous rank else previous rank + 1). Use VLOOKUP to insert ranking  into source table then special paste to fix it.

Comment: @Akina I am sorry I didn't get it. I created a pivot table, even if I wasn't able to create a ranking. But if I did this would not create only 10 rankings, but more. How can I create "appropriate" intervals for my table and transform them into rankings?

Comment: @Roberto,, are you need rank for each category like Mammals Domestic, Mammals Wild, Birds & Fish or General Ranking using the Total Column,, or I could guess that you want to SORT name of Animals , Birds & other on their Category ,,, be specific of add expected output or the Formula you have tried so far !!!

Comment: Have you tried using PercentRank (or even just Rank) and then modifying the results to standardise this on a 1-10 scale? I don't have Mac so cannot be sure PercentRank is an available function, but I would expect it to be there.

Comment: @AdamV thank you, I did that!